# PDF url embedded in R Shiny Iframe asking user to download file now

Tags: r, pdf, amazon-s3, shinydashboard

I have a Shiny app that creates a reactive pdf url based on user selections (example https://mycompany.com/4.pdf) where the 4 is a dynamic input selection.  These urls are all valid and app has worked fine by using tags$iframe in the server where the src is set to this reactive string value.

Company has transitioned these pdfs to a AWS S3 host, still using the same urls though.  Now when users open the app, it does not display the pdf in the iframe it had been doing but prompts the user to download/open the pdf file separately.  This is happening in edge browser.

Side note, I had to have my customers use edge because original working version of the embedded iframe would show as blank in Firefox, but display fine in edge.

I am not familiar with S3 and would would be causing this now, any help is appreciated.

- if I try the pdf url in a stand alone browser session in edge, it does the same download/open prompt, but in Firefox it will display in browser.  But for some reason the iframe is blank in Firefox shiny.

As described above, I tried different browsers.  I also looked into downloading the pdf into a temp file and displaying that temp file in the iframe but the temp pdf doesn’t appear to be “complete”.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.